# Avoid different page numbers in viewer software and on when using frontmatter

Tags: page-numbering, viewers, front-matter

The problem should be clear with this MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter 

\chapter*{Frontmatter}
\blindtext

\mainmatter 

\chapter{Chapter 1}

This chapter is on page 1 (bottom right, what would be printed), but my pdf reader says it is on page 3.

\end{document}
```

For compilation, I use `pdflatex`.

Expected behavior: My pdf reader software shall land on page n when I tell it to go on page n.

I spent now well over an hour trying suggestions that I could find on google and tex.stackexchange without success. I would be very grateful if someone could post a solution to this problem!

Comment: Doesn't that depend on which pdf viewer you use? Some viewers can display "logical page numbers".

Comment: `pdflatex` is targeted towards producing a printed document in PDF format with printed page numbers according to the LaTeX code, which may be Arabic or Roman in different portions of thje document. Normally it does not output the sequence of pages from the start of the document, independently of their representation. PDF viewers typically depend on the printed page number representation not their underlying sequence. Perhaps if you were able (via a package or a class) to enable sequential page numbers in your document you could get your PDF viewer do do what who want.